# WPF: What is between the Initialized and Loaded event?

Tags: c#, wpf, events, window

I want to run some code when the Window or Control is first displayed. I can't use Loaded because that can fire more than once. I can't use Initialized because that is done by the constructor.

Is there an event somewhere between?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no such event.  You can use a boolean in the Loaded Method to make sure your stuff only fires once -

```
if(!IsSetUp)
{
   MySetUpFunction();
   IsSetUp = true;
}
```

Check out the WPF Windows lifetime events here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748948.aspx#Window_Lifetime_Events

[image]
<sub>(source: [microsoft.com](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC155674.png))</sub>

Comment: Well that's stupid, I shouldn't have to use guard clauses like that. But it's the right answer so here's your point.

Comment: Agreed - you could create your own window class inheriting from window and implement an event across your whole project if it's something your doing frequently.

Comment: Please also see this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehillberg/archive/2006/09/19/loadedvsinitialized.aspx

Comment: There is indeed such an event, inherited by `Window` from `FrameworkElement`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.initialized.aspx

Comment: From this picture, I don't see `Loaded` can fire more than once, anything I missed?

Answer (score 8):

Alternatively to storing a boolean flag, you can use an extension method and delegate wrapping to fake `Loaded` only firing once.

```
public static void OnLoadedOnce(
    this UserControl control,
    RoutedEventHandler onLoaded)
{
    if (control == null || onLoaded == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException();
    }

    RoutedEventHandler wrappedOnLoaded = null;
    wrappedOnLoaded = delegate(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        control.Loaded -= wrappedOnLoaded;
        onLoaded(sender, e);
    };
    control.Loaded += wrappedOnLoaded;
}

...

class MyControl : UserControl
{
    public MyControl()
    { 
        InitializeComponent();
        this.OnLoadedOnce(this.OnControlLoaded /* or delegate {...} */);
    }

    private void OnControlLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to use the boolean method of doing things, then you can create a method and subscribe to the `Loaded` event with it, then unsubscribe at the end of that method.

Example:

```
public MyDependencyObject(){
  Loaded += OnLoaded;
}

private void OnLoaded(object sender, EventArgs args){
  DoThings();
  Loaded -= OnLoaded;
}
```