# How to make UserControl initialization only once after property is set

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-controls

Code:

```
public partial class MyControl : UserControl
{
    int size = 8;

    public int Size
    {
        get { return size; }
        set { size = value; Initialize(); }
    }

    public MyControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Initialize();
    }

    void Initialize()
    {
         // ...
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<local:MyControl"/>
```

or:

```
<local:MyControl Size="10"/>
```

When `Size` property is set in XAML, `Initialize` is called twice. If I remove `Initialize` call from `InitializeComponent`, `Initialize` is called once from `Size` setter. But in this case, if `Size` is not set in XAML, `Initialize` is not called at all.

Is there any way to write initialization function, which is executed once, after all control properties (if any) are set from XAML?

Comment: While you could use the `Loaded` event, it can still get called multiple times(the event itself, and thus your function). If you only want your function run once maybe have a bool class member to detect if the function has already been called and ignore any future calls of the function silently? Something like : [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3303050/1834662)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may call the `Initialize` method in a `Loaded` event handler:

```
public partial class MyControl : UserControl
{
    int size = 8;

    public int Size
    {
        get { return size; }
        set { size = value; }
    }

    public MyControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Loaded += (o, e) => Initialize();
    }

    void Initialize()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

---

In order to make sure the `Initialize()` method is called only once, although `Loaded` may be fired more than once, detach the event handler like this:

```
public MyControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Loaded += MyControlLoaded;
}

private void MyControlLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Loaded -= MyControlLoaded;
    Initialize();
}
```