# WPF, issues when editing stackpanel contents from the child's constructor

Tags: c#, wpf

So, in my MainWindow I have this (the latest attempt at trying to postpone the function call to cleanup to a point where everything *might* be initialized properly.

```cs
 public void replaceView(UserControl ctrl)
 {
   contentContainer.Children.Add(ctrl);

   ctrl.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
   {

     DoubleAnimation db = new DoubleAnimation();
     db.From = contentContainer.ActualHeight;
     db.To = 0;
     db.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.500);

     DoubleAnimation db2 = new DoubleAnimation();
     db2.From = 0;
     db2.To = 1920;
     db2.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.500);
     db2.Completed += (sender2, eArgs) => cleanupStackPanel(ctrl);

     contentContainer.Children[0].BeginAnimation(UserControl.HeightProperty, db);
     contentContainer.Children[1].BeginAnimation(UserControl.HeightProperty, db2);
     }), System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Loaded);
 }



 public void cleanupStackPanel(UserControl ctrl)
 {

   for (int i = 0; i < contentContainer.Children.Count; i++)
   {
     var item = (UserControl)contentContainer.Children[i];
     if (item != ctrl)
     {
       contentContainer.Children.Remove(item);
       i--;
     }
   }
   if(contentContainer.Children.Count == 0)
   {
     contentContainer.Children.Add(new OrangeSplashScreen());
   }
   if(ctrl.Name == "EnterScreen")
   {
     CodeEntryScreen c = (CodeEntryScreen)ctrl;
     c.Enter_Click(null, null);
   }
 }
```

contentContainer is a StackPanel.

I then use this in my UserControls like this

```
 MainWindow win = Window.GetWindow(App.Current.MainWindow) as MainWindow;
 win.replaceView(new WhateverUserControl());
```

This works wonderfully, if the replaceView is called in a MouseDown on a label or similar.. However when this is called directly in the constructor of the new UserControl,`

```
 public PrintOrSpecifyScreen(List<JToken> printableTickets)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.DataContext = this;
            this.printableTickets = printableTickets;

           if(true) {
               MainWindow win = Window.GetWindow(App.Current.MainWindow) as MainWindow;
               win.replaceView(new WhateverUserControl());
           }
        }
```

this results in `if(contentContainer.Children.Count == 0)` being true when it shouldn't be and the new control gets replaced with the orange splash screen UserControl. What could I do to mitigate this?

Answer (score 1):

Because of the way XAML is parsed, the `UserControl` won't have any children at the time it's constructed. If you want to defer execution of code until the control has been fully loaded, you should handle the `Loaded` event:

```
    public PrintOrSpecifyScreen()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += this.OnLoaded;
    }

    private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // ...
    }
```

See [Object lifetime events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/events/object-lifetime-events?view=netdesktop-7.0) for details.

Comment: Be aware that loaded can fire unintentionally and multiple times... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3302987/wpf-what-is-between-the-initialized-and-loaded-event

Comment: I tried that. 
```
 public PrintOrSpecifyScreen(List<JToken> printableTickets)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.DataContext = this;
            this.printableTickets = printableTickets;

            this.Loaded += OnLoaded;
        }

        private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MainWindow win = Window.GetWindow(App.Current.MainWindow) as MainWindow;
            win.replaceView(new PlanScreen());
        }
```
And the same still happens

Comment: Could it be that the printorspecify screen itself is added through the same replaceView method (although on a mousedown) ?

Comment: private void ContinueButton_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            MainWindow win = Window.GetWindow(App.Current.MainWindow) as MainWindow;
            win.replaceView(new PrintOrSpecifyScreen(printableTickets));
        }